# What is the maximum value of $M$ when $T$ is set of $\{2,4,8,16,... 2^n\}$ and $S$ is subset of $T$ by given conditions

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

> Qns
>
> $T$ is set of $\{2,4,8,16,... 2^n\}$ and $S$ is a subset of $T$
>
> if the sum of no two elements of $S$ is greater than $2^n-2$.
>
> let $m$ be $M$ number of elements in $S$.
> what is the maximum value of $M$?

My approach:

$S$ has $2$ elements for example $2,4$

Sum$=6 = 2+4$

$2^2-2=2$

Therefore,$6>2$, which is false as specified in the question.

Similarly I put $3$ elements

$S=\{2,4,8\}$ sum$=14$

$2^3-2$, which is $6$

Thus, the condition is false as specified in the question.

$S=\{2,4,8,16\}$  sum$=30>14$, which is false as specified in the question.

I could not solve and think of as the numbers are not specifying the condition.

Comment: Depends. Do you mean that sums of pairs of elements may not exceed $2^n-2$, or is the bound $2^{n-2}$? Your numerical example suggests the former, André (among others) thought you mean the latter. You should clarify (and make the distinction clear in your notation). Towards the end it becomes gibberishy. Why are you suddenly including 6?

Comment: @AndréNicolas U mean m has max 5 element?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Yes sum of pairs of element may not exceed 2^n−2.2 raise to power of n

Comment: @AndréNicolas but as u can see(Consider any two numbers) when i added 2 numbers their sum was 6 and 2^2-2 is equal to 2.When,6>2 which means their sum cannot be greater than 2^n-2.So,do we need to add 3 numbers sum and then add it into set S and see how many maximum numbers we can add?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: @AndréNicolas i need to find the maximum value in set S?what is the maximum value n has?Accoring to me it is n only

Comment: If you are using $2^n-2$, and $n\ge 3$, the maximum number of numbers in $T$ such that no sum of two is greater than $2^n-2$ is $n-1$. The biggest set $S$ uses everybody but $2^n$ Your "let $m$ be $M$ number" is not clear.  And the entire problem, as written, is far too easy. I wonder whether it was originally not in English, and got mistranslated.

Comment: Let $n\ge 3$. Let $a$ and $b$ be any two elements of $T$, neither of which is $2^n$. Their sum is $\le 2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}$. And $2^{n-2}\le 2^{n-1}-2$, so their sum is $\le 2\cdot 2^{n-1}-2=2^n-2$, Thus if $S$ has every element of $T$ other than $2^n$, the sum of any two elements of $S$ is $\le 2^n-2$.  Finally, $T$ has $n$ elements, so if we put into $S$ all but $2^n$, we have put in $n-1$ numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is my statement right Consider n>=3 so we have more than  3 elements in T i.e 1,3,5 or 1,3,5,7 (neither of the form $2$^n).Now,their sum is coming to be not less than $2$^n-1 + $2$^n-2.1Q How you got their sum less than or equal to $2$^n-1 + $2$^n-2

Comment: All the elements of $T$ are powers of $2$, so I don't understand why you are considering $1,3,7$. I wrote that $2^{n-2}\le 2^{n-1}-2$ because we have equality at $n=3$ and if $n\gt 3$ then the difference $2^{n-1}-2^{n-2}$ is greater than $2$. For it is $2^{n-1}-2^{n-2}=2^{n-2}$.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas okay i understood your statement.I understood that statement wrong when you said   Let a and b be any two elements of T, (neither of which is 2^n).

Comment: @AndréNicolas What do this statement mean now "Thus if S has every element of T other than $2^n$, the sum of any two elements of S is <=$2^n-2$."

Comment: It means that the set $S=\{2,4,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$, then $S$ is a subset of $T$ that satisfies your condition that the sum of any two members is $\le 2^n-2$.